# Submit Not Working on Form

Tags: php, css, forms, form-submit

I'm sorry for asking this question. I'm still a relatively new website builder and forms have always been a pain for me. I've searched and tried a number of ideas others have posted to similar questions and this form is yet to work. I used it on a previous site and it worked wonderfully. I copied the exact code and added a few checkboxes, pasted it into my new site. Now when I click on the submit button it just sits and spins.

Any suggestions or edits to my code will be greatly appreciated.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="contact_form" name="contact_form">
    <div class="name">
        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <p> Please enter your full name</p>
        <input id=name name=name type=text placeholder="e.g. John Smith" required />
    </div>
    <div class="email">
        <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
        <p> Please enter your email address</p>
        <input id=email name=email type=email placeholder="example@domain.com" required />
    </div>
    <div class="email">
        <label for="phone">Your phone number:</label>
        <p> Please enter your phone number</p>
        <input id=phone name=phone type=phone placeholder="555-555-5555" required />
    </div>
    <div class="company">
        <label for="company">Your Company:</label>
        <p> Please enter your company name</p>
        <input id=company name=company type=company placeholder="Your Company Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="companyweb">
        <label for="companyweb">Your Company Website:</label>
        <p> Please enter your company website</p>
        <input id=companyweb name=companyweb type=companyweb placeholder="Your Company Website" required />
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox">How can we serve you?</label>
        <p> Please check all that apply</p>
        <p> Consulting:</p>
        <p><input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Consulting: Operations Improvements" />Operations Improvements<br>
            <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Consulting: Process Improvements" />Process Improvements<br>
            <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Consulting: Order Fulfillment" />Order Fulfillment<br>
            <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Consulting: Technology Analysis &amp; Selection" />Technology Analysis &amp; Selection<br>
            <p>Design &amp; Engineering:</p>
            <p><input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Design &amp; Engineering: New Facility" />New Facility<br>
                <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Design &amp; Engineering: Retro-fit" />Retro-fit<br>
                <p>Technology:</p>
                <p><input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Technology: Order Fulfillment" />Order Fulfillment<br>
                    <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="-  Technology: ERP Integration" />ERP Integration<br>
                    <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Technology: Incentive Payroll Solution" />Incentive Payroll Solution<br>
                    <p>Equipment:</p>
                    <p><input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Equipment: Automated Pack/Ship" />Automated Pack/Ship<br>
                        <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Equipment: Vertical &amp; Horizontal Storage Solutions" />Vertical &amp; Horizontal Storage Solutions<br>
                        <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Equipment: Material Handling Systems" />Material Handling Systems<br>
                        <input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Equipment: Carts/Carton Flow/Work Stations" />Carts/Carton Flow/Work Stations<br>
                        <p></p>
                        <p><input id=checkbox name=checkbox[] type="checkbox" value="- Other." />Other<br>
                            <input id="othertext" name="othertext" type="text"  class="text required" / >
                        </p>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="loader">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>


<?php
$emailSubject = 'Contact Us Form';
$name = $_POST ['name'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$phone = $_POST ['phone'];
$company = $_POST ['company'];
$companyweb = $_POST ['companyweb'];
$checkbox = implode(' ', $_POST['checkbox']);
$othertext = $_POST ['othertext'];

$body = <<<EOD
Name: $name
Email: $email
Phone: $phone
Company: $company
Company Website: $companyweb
How Can We Serve You: $checkbox
Message: $othertext

EOD;
mail( "myemail@email.com", "Talk to Us",
$body, "From: $email" );
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "Your email was sent successfully.";
}  else {
    echo 'There was a problem sending your email.';

}  
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, it would be easier for us to help you if you try to indent your code and show the minimal lines of codes.

Comment: I re-indented the code, which makes it a bit easier to see that the HTML itself is missing a lot of closing tags (including closing the form itself). It's probably worth fixing that up first, and as @goto said, try making a minimal version of the code that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also no idea why this was marked as a duplicate. I don't see any relationship between this question and the linked question.